# Omitting prefix in XPATH (libxml2) leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c, xml, xpath, segmentation-fault, libxml2

I installed [C libxml2 version 2.9.4 library](http://xmlsoft.org/) on my Mac (`Darwin <hostname> 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`) using the standard `./configure ; make ; make install` trifecta of commands. On trying to run the `testXPath` command with the `-tree` option on an XPATH without a prefix, I get a segmentation fault.

```
~/home/libxml2-2.7.2 $ ./testXPath -tree "/abcde"
In testXPath function...
Compiled Expression : 0 elements  
  END
    END
      END
        END
          END
            END
              END
                END
                  END
                    END
                      END
                        END
                          END
                            END
                              END
                                END
                                  END
                                    END
                                      END
                                        END
                                          END
                                            END
                                              END
                                                END
                                                  END
                                                  END
                                                  END
                                                  END
                                                  END
                                                  END
                                                  END
...etc until:
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I dug in a bit into the `testXPath.c` code, and the compilation of the XPATH seems to be faulty.

```
comp = xmlXPathCompile(BAD_CAST str);
```

The `xmlXPathCompExprPtr` returned has its `last` member set to be `-1` if I don't supply a prefix. This causes the call to `xmlXPathDebugDumpCompExpr()` to glitch out.

Having a prefix in the xpath doesn't cause the fault. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted.

Comment: Sadly, SO allows you to downvote without stating any reason. Sometimes it just means someone is having a bad day.

Answer (score 0):

`testXPath` is part of the libxml2 test suite and isn't expected to be run directly by users. If you want to test XPath expressions with libxml2, use `xmllint` with the `--xpath` option:

```
xmllint --xpath 'expr' XMLFILE
```

Comment: `xmlXPathCompile()`, however, *is* a part of the library intended for users. That is what is returning faulty values.

Comment: @ShivanKaul If you think there's a bug in `xmlXPathCompile` then file a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/).